# How do I verify that all memory allocations have been freed between two checkpoints?

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have a process that seems to be leaking memory. The longer the process runs, the more memory it uses. That is in spite of the fact that the process consists primarily of a loop that iteratively calls a function which should not preserve any data between calls. When I use valgrind to check for leaks, everything comes back a-ok. When the process eventually exits after running for a few hours, there is a substantial delay at exit, which all leads me to believe that memory is being allocated in that function and not freed immediately because it is still referenced.  The memory is then subsequently freed on exit because that reference is eventually freed.

I'm wondering if there is a way with valgrind (or some other linux-compatible tool) to do a leak check between two code checkpoints.  I'd like to get a leak report of all memory that was allocated but not freed between two code checkpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an [article](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1905) on this a few years back.

In short, you include valgrind.h and then you can use macros like

VALGRIND_DO_LEAK_CHECK

Alternatively you can attach gdb and issue the 'monitor leak_check' command. This can be incremental. See [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands)